# Max and Min in a loop for C#

Tags: c#, max, min

I am making a code where the user is asked, "How many marks are there?" and then they put in the number of marks they mentioned. After that, it prints out the maximum mark and the minimum mark.

```
            int MarkNumber;
            Console.Write("How many marks are there?: ");
            MarkNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int SchoolM = 0; SchoolM < MarkNumber; SchoolM++)
            { 
                Console.Write("Input a Mark: ");
                Console.ReadLine();                   
            }
```

I am not the best at coding so I have no direction of how to find the max and min in a loop. I got up to the part where they are able to input the marks, but I am unsure of how to find the max and the min. I have looked up how to do the max and min, but it usually shows up for finding the max and min in arrays and that is not what I desire to do.

Comment: Before the loop: `int currentMark; int min = 0; int max = 0;`. Inside the loop: `currentMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); if (currentMark > max) max = currentMark; else if (currentMark < min) min = currentMark;`. Alternatively, you could add the marks to a list and calculate the min and max afterward.

Comment: Side note: when dealing with user input, always prefer [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) over `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: Oh alright, I would use other alternatives, but I am still inexperienced. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be use variables one for max number and other for lower number

Maybe something like it

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {

    {
        int MarkNumber;
        int iminor = -1;
        int imax = 0;
        Console.Write("How many marks are there?: ");
        MarkNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int SchoolM = 0; SchoolM < MarkNumber; SchoolM++)
        { 
            Console.Write("Input a Mark: ");
            int mark = 0;
            do
            {
                var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(userInput, out int i))
                {
                    Console.Write("Try again ");
                }
                else
                {
                    mark = i;
                    break;
                }                    
            } while (true);            
            if (mark > imax) imax = mark;
            if (mark < iminor) iminor = mark;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($" Minor Mark {iminor} Max Mark {imax}");
    }
```

Comment: I think iminor should be intialized to Int32.MaxValue otherwise if all marks are positive, min will be always zero.

Comment: Ooooh, yes now that I think about that it is easier for me to do that. Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: @carlos-cocom you should initialize `imax` to `System.Int32.MinValue` and `iminor` to `System.Int32.MaxValue`. That way the script may also handle negative numbers which are valid integers.
And `Convert.ToInt32()` may throw an exception, so that should be handled as well, either by wrapping it inside a try-block, or by using a more defensive style such as `Int32.TryParse()`.

Comment: @ワイきんぐ i understand but in this case more simple just for learning is, ok or what 
 do you think?

Comment: If the user only enters negative numbers you have a bug with `imax`, so I would definitely fix that. :) StackOverflow is also about posting bug-free code that others may (read: will) copy-paste.